# Maintain both value and label from react-select component in redux-form state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-select

A Select component in react-select maintains state in both `label` and `value` values. The advice I have seen to date on integrating this component into a redux-form form, recommends overwriting the default react-select `onChange` and `onBlur` behaviour with one passed down implicitly from a parent redux-form  component. For example...

```js
<Field component{SelectWrapper} />

class SelectWrapper extends React.Component {
    onChange = event => {
       if (this.props.input.onChange && event != null) {
          this.props.input.onChange(event.value);
       } else {
          this.props.input.onChange(null);
       }
    }
    render() {
         <AsyncCreatableSelect 
           {...this.props}
           onChange={this.onChange}
           onBlur={() => this.props.input.onBlur(this.props.input.value)}
         />
    }
}
```

I would like to populate the `<Select />` component from a MongoDB store using the document's `_id` as the `value` and the `name` property as the `label`. Then when selecting another option I would like to see that `name` in the select box whilst maintaining the `id` as the value. This is so the user can select from meaningful items whilst I can have some guarantees when submitting the form and pushing it back to the data store. Is there a good or correct way to do this?

My code so far...

```js
// CustomerSelect.js
import React from "react";
import { Field } from "redux-form";
import Grid from "material-ui/Grid";
import renderAsyncCreatableSelect from "../redux-form-connectors/renderAsyncCreatableSelect";

const CustomerSelect = ({ customers,  selectedCustomer }) => {
    // customers: [{name: "Alice", _id: "$7637221n...}, ...]
    const options = customers.map(customer => ({
      label: customer,
      value: customer
    }));
    return (
      <Grid item>
        <Field
          name="customer"
          component={renderAsyncCreatableSelect}
          label="Customer"
          selectedValue={selectedCustomer}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  };

// renderAsyncCreatableSelect.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AsyncCreatableSelect from "react-select/lib/AsyncCreatable";

const getOptions = () => {
  return axios
    .get("/api/customers") // [{_id: "", name: "", user: ""... }, ...]
    .then(res => res.data.map(el => ({ label: el.name, value: el._id })));
};

export default class renderAsyncCreatableSelect extends Component {
  onChange = (event) => {
    if (this.props.input.onChange && event != null) {
      this.props.input.onChange(event.value);
    } else {
      this.props.input.onChange(null);
    }
  };


  render() {
    const { input, selectedValue } = this.props;

    return (
      <AsyncCreatableSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        placeholder={"Customer..."}
        loadOptions={getOptions}
        value={input.value ? input.value : selectedValue.label}
        onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onchange function must look like

```
onChange = (event) => {
    if (this.props.input.onChange && event.target.value != null) {
      this.props.input.onChange(target.value);
    } else {
      this.props.input.onChange(null);
    }
  };
```

or if you are using redux from field

```
onChange = (event, value) => {
        if (this.props.input.onChange && value != null) {
          this.props.input.onChange(value);
        } else {
          this.props.input.onChange(null);
        }
      };
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but if I console.log(value) I see {action: "select-option"} and the field label doesn't update.